# how can i save a js variable in a php table?

Tags: javascript, php

after calculating the grade of a quiz in a js file i'm trying to take that variable to update the grade, of that particular student in a php file.

the script is executed in the user area where the user id is set.

*errors*: The indicated user is not updated, probably the variable doesn't arrive or php is not set up properly;

to transport the grade variable from js to the php file i used this code which is executed at the end of the quiz

**quiz.js**

```
var vote = userScore * 10;

window.open('/php/vote.php?vote='+vote);
```

**private-area.php**

```
<?php
    require 'php/config.php';

    $_SESSION["id_utente"];

    $sessionId = $_SESSION["id_utente"];
    
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connessione, "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE id_utente = $sessionId"));
?>
```

**vote.php**    (first time i update)

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

$var_voto = $_GET['vote'];


if($connessione->connect_error){
    echo "Registrazione avvenuta con successo";

    $query = $connessione->prepare("UPDATE utenti SET voto = $var_voto  WHERE id = $user ");
    $query->bind_param('voto', $id);
    $result = $query->execute();

}else{
    echo "Error";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **bindParam**  like below

$query = $connessione->prepare("UPDATE utenti SET voto = :var_voto  WHERE id = :user ");

$query->bindParam(':var_voto',$var_voto);

$query->bindParam(':user', $user );

Comment: tells me Undefined method 'bindParam'

Comment: This is for PDO so actually incorrect as you are using mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql appears incorrect. You shouldn't be using variables inside SQL queries, certainly not with prepared statements to avoid any SQL injection.

Try

```
$query = $connessione->prepare("UPDATE utenti SET voto = ? WHERE id = ?");
$query->bind_param('ii', $var_voto, $user);
$result = $query->execute();
```

This is assuming that `voto` and `id` in your database are integer types. If they are strings/varchar replace `ii` with `ss` in `bind_param`.

By way of an explanation, use `?` to specify parameterised data inside your prepared query and bind them with the data using `bind_param`. The first argument is the data type, we're using `i` for integers in the above code, and two of them (i.e. `ii`) because we're binding two parameters (`$var_voto` and `$user`) See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php for more.
The second, third, forth, fifth etc argument are the variables containing the data we wish to insert (or bind) to the query.

Comment: do you know how i can transfer the session user in this php file?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "transfer"

Comment: I would like to send the variable $user which is in private-area.php to vote.php

Comment: You would need to redeclare it inside vote.php. The typically common way would be to use sessions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php